# for each loop won't work php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm having problems figuring out why this for each loop won't work. When I print out the result, it shows correctly according to the salaries array but when I try to use the data later in the code (Doing salary*tax) it just does it ones and it wont loop through accordingly.. I'm very new to coding so please understand :P

```
<?php




$salaries =array(
635000.00, 420000.00, 260000.00, 150000.00, 550000.00, 90000.00);
foreach ($salaries as $a)
{
if ($a >= 500000) 
{$t =0.45;
echo $t;
}
else
{
if ($a>=300000 and ($a<=500000))
{$t=0.35;
echo $t;
}
if ($a>=200000 and ($a<=300000))
{$t=0.2;
echo $t;
}
if ($a>=100000 and ($a<=200000))
{$t=0.1;
echo $t;
{
if ($a>= 100000) 
{$t =0;
echo $t;    
}}}}}




?>
($salaries[0]*$t)
```

works fine, but down in the array I have for other members it just keeps picking 0.45% as the right tax amount.

Comment: What foreach loop? your code as posted above is a flat-out syntax error. And even if it was correct, almost ALL of the values in your array are bigger than 10,000, so the final $t=0 will ALWAYS run, and trash any $t you set earlier in other if() tests.

Comment: You don't need the `<=` conditions as salaries too high will already have been treated by one of the if conditions above.

Comment: Shouldn't `if ($a>= 100000)` be `if ($a<= 100000)` instead?

Comment: can you explain what exactly want to do? If you're newbie we can help but the code is a mess.

Comment: I managed to figure it out myself finally ;) ! Thanks for looking into it tho

Answer (score 0):

Even though this code don't make alot of sense as to what it is doing, here is a fix:

```
$salaries =array(635000.00, 420000.00, 260000.00, 150000.00, 550000.00, 90000.00);
foreach($salaries as $a)
{
    if ($a >= 500000) 
    {
        $t =0.45;
        echo $t;
    }
    elseif ($a>=300000 and ($a<=500000))
    {
        $t=0.35;
        echo $t;
    }
    elseif ($a>=200000 and ($a<=300000))
    {
        $t=0.2;
        echo $t;
    }
    elseif ($a>=100000 and ($a<=200000))
    {
        $t=0.1;
        echo $t;
    }
    else
    {
        $t =0;
        echo $t;    
    }
}
```

Comment: @user2836607 Could this be something?

Answer (score 0):

I figure out that you want to calculate taxes for every salary, in that case (using your coding style):

```
<?php
$salaries = array(
  635000.00,
  420000.00,
  260000.00,
  150000.00,
  550000.00,
  90000.00
);
foreach ($salaries as $salary) {
  if ($salary >= 500000) {
    $tax = 0.45;
    echo "<p>Salary: $salary x Tax: $tax = " . $salary * $tax . "</p>";
  } else {
    if ($salary >= 300000 and ($salary <= 500000)) {
      $tax = 0.35;
      echo "<p>Salary: $salary x Tax: $tax = " . $salary * $tax . "</p>";
    }
    if ($salary >= 200000 and ($salary <= 300000)) {
      $tax = 0.2;
      echo "<p>Salary: $salary x Tax: $tax = " . $salary * $tax . "</p>";
    }
    if ($salary >= 100000 and ($salary <= 200000)) {
      $tax = 0.1;
      echo "<p>Salary: $salary x Tax: $tax = " . $salary * $tax . "</p>"; {
        if ($salary <= 100000) {
          $tax = 0;
          echo "<p>Salary: $salary x Tax: $tax = " . $salary * $tax . "</p>";
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Output:

```
Salary: 635000 x Tax: 0.45 = 285750
Salary: 420000 x Tax: 0.35 = 147000
Salary: 260000 x Tax: 0.2 = 52000
Salary: 150000 x Tax: 0.1 = 15000
Salary: 550000 x Tax: 0.45 = 247500
```